# Python:: Unicode characters garbled while writing in file

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8

My requirement is to read some data from mysql database, and then write it in a JSON format to a file. However, while writing into file, the unicode data is garbled.

```
Actual Unicode Name: ぎぎぎは.exe
Name written to file: ã<81>Žã<81>Žã<81>Žã<81>¯.exe
```

My database has charset set as utf8. I am opening connection like below:

```
MySQLdb.connect (host = "XXXXX", user = "XXXXX", passwd = "XXXX", cursorclass=cursors.SSCursor,charset='utf8',use_unicode=True)
```

And the outfile is opened as below:

```
for r in data:
 with open("XX.json",'w') as out:
  d={}
  d['name']=r[0]
  d['type']='Work'
  out.write('%s\n' % json.dumps(d, indent=0, ensure_ascii=False).replace('\n', ''))
```

This is working, but as mentioned above unicode data is getting garbled.

If I do type(r[0]), it's coming as 'str'.

If your solution includes to use codes.open function, with encoding as 'utf-8', then please help me add decode/encode whereever required. This method needs all data to be unicode.

I am lost in plethora of solution available online, but none of them are working perfectly fine for me :(

OS Details: CentOS 6

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'UTF-8'
>>>
```

Comment: If you are using Python 3, you just need to `open("XX.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides I am using Python 2.6.6. For some reasons, I can not upgrade my python module.

Comment: Read this to understand better what is unicode an text transforms. That is regardless of anyone putting a receipt with the right thing to do onyour case, you have to understand this. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: And then, switch to Python3

Comment: How are you opening the file? Maybe it is being saved correctly, but without BOM so your text editor uses some other default encoding to display it?

Comment: What's the output of `json.dumps(d, indent=0, ensure_ascii=False)` if that looks correct in a print then you're probably just viewing the file with a wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try `io.open`:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import json
import io
with io.open('b.txt', 'at', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
  json_file.write(json.dumps({u'ぎぎぎは': 0}, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8'))
```

Comment: It was discussed in the comments that the OP uses Python 2.

Comment: Excellent, me too

Comment: Oh, sorry :-) Actually I didn't know about `io` in Python 2.